# How to get list of Scripts in Order of Dependencies

Tags: plugins, wp-dependencies

I was writing plugin for combining JS and CSS as three plugins I tried has not worked for me. 
Dependency problem is where I stopped. It look tough. Then I thought Wordpress can itself help.

How to get list of files in order of dependencies? Is there any WP method for this? Can I use WP_dependency class externally? How?

I am able to filter script files according to Header and Footer.

Answer (score 4):

All the information you need you can get from the global variable `$wp_scripts`:

**Code:**

```
function wpse124227_wp_script_styles_debug_basic() {
    global $wp_scripts, $wp_styles;
    echo '<pre>';
        //Scripts
        print_r( $wp_scripts );
        //Styles
        //print_r( $wp_styles );
    echo '</pre>';
    }
add_filter( 'wp_head', 'wpse124227_wp_script_styles_debug_basic' );
```

To get a more specific output you have to define what you are looking for, instead of printing the whole object. Below linked information should get you started on that.

**Information:**

- [How do I get the $handle for all enqueued scripts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54064/how-do-i-get-the-handle-for-all-enqueued-scripts)
- [Debug enqueued Scripts and Styles in WordPress](http://wpengineer.com/2308/debug-enqueued-scripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/)
- [Add a script as a dependency to a registered script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100709/add-a-script-as-a-dependency-to-a-registered-script)

---

**Update:**

I just remembered there is a add-on to the [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin, called 
[Debug Bar List Script & Style Dependencies](http://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-list-dependencies/)
, which does show scipts and styles dependencies and orders them. *But* I don't know how the add-on does it, never looked at the code, and if that's exactly what you want. You'd have to inspect that yourself.

Comment: That I know, but that does not comes in order of dependency. In `deps` key, dependency is there but it would be big work to get the order based on dependency. So, I thought there would be any way to get in order using WP own's way!

Comment: Like I said, you have to construct specific output yourself. Dependencies are given in the object, now you only need to order them. @SatyaPrakash